# Using access token without facebook log in (Graph API)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm working with javascript and i've made a site for only one person (admin), who needs to log in to Facebook and then the script extracts data from many public pages on facebook through some ids i've saved in a local database.

What i'd like to do now is actually the same, but without user interaction. This means the admin shouldn't log in his facebook account to start viewing facebook pages stats.

Is there anyway to code making use of a token (I've read that you can make them permanent) and instead of logging in to facebook in your welcome page, just start watching pages stats? Is there anyway to just skip the log in pop up from Facebook?

Comment: _“Is there anyway to just skip the log in pop up from Facebook?”_ - sure, just _don’t_ trigger it then ... Making API calls has nothing to do with login.

Comment: @CBroe but even if I dont trigger it, doesn't that still means that the fb account must be logged in order to make calls? Isn't there some way to just use a page access token and paste it onto the code after making a call for it?

Comment: Yes, by getting an extended one ...

Comment: Or, if the pages are fully public and their posts not targeted to specific audiences, the app access token will do.